# parsing an XML file in gnome shell extension

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

It looks like there is no way to parse an XML file in the actual gnome shell tool extension.

This means you can not parse svg.

Any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

partially solved with E4X, to parse SVG I had to setup default xml namespace.

```
default xml namespace = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
```

Comment: I would like to parse xml files using gnome extension system and your answer is not complete IMO. Any news about a XML parser ? I read about E4X but no documentation found. Plus, i read than libxml2 is outdated.

Comment: I made my application differently, in order to remove this need . And finally left gnome for KDE plasma, because their gnome shell extension api was changing everything time. With KDE, I managed to do in few days what I was not able to do in months with gnome. you will have documentations and community help in KDE , that you will not find in gnome community. In Kde you will write a kde plasmoid and being able to parse xml.

Comment: Nice to read, but i can't move to KDE. You are right, Gnome is changing API and all 2011 GJS documentation is outdated. But now, **you** have the ability to contribute to the gnome documentation by answering your question. Stackoverflow is a kind of documentation. Please can you put an answer to your question ? Thanks in advance.